# IMAP with gmail

Tags: php, instagram

I am doing to fetch the emails from my gmail account. its work in localserver like localhost.. but when i try to fetch the email from server it give the timeout error. 
can anyone help me?

> Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in /home/appdeal/public_html/appDeal/getmail2.php on line 9
>   Cannot connect to Tiriyo: Can't connect to gmail-imap.l.google.com,993: Connection timed out

url : http://appdeal.com/appDeal/getmail2.php

Comment: Have you verified the network connectivity is there itself?  You can get to imap.gmail.com:993 using e.g. telnet?

Comment: no i did not.. can u please elaborate me about this.. how to use it with server.. please

Comment: e.g. in Windows the command `telnet imap.gmail.com 993` will either connect (might show a blank screen, or some welcome message - in which case you know it's your code that is wrong, not the network) or show an error message like "timed out" or "connect failed" or whatever (in which case it is not your code).  "Timed out" in your question suggests the code is reporting correctly - and telling you why it didn't work.  NB

Comment: NB Windows does not always have telnet installed by default but it can usually be added; or maybe you aren't using Windows and the syntax might be different then.

Comment: I am using it on cpanel .. its working on my localhost but problem is occur when i implement it on server.. or cpanel... what is solution for it when i used it on server.

Comment: Why does this have the `instagram` tag? This is completely irrelevant.